# Skip math calculation if key, value and result is already stored in dictionary using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm doing a simple exercise here but I can't quite get the result I want. I have 2 simple function and in the second function `run` is to skip `compute` function and directly give the result of `a+b` if the key and value provided are the same than its previous one when execute the print function, but not sure how to update the result into the dictionary `x`.

Below is my code :

```
import time


def compute(a,b):
    time.sleep(1)
    return a+b


x = {}


def run(a,b):
    if a & b in x:
        return x
    else:
        x.update({a:b})
        return compute(a,b)


print(run(5,7))
print(run(5,7))
print(run(2,5))
print(run(2,4))
print(run(5,7))
print(run(2,4))
```

and the result I get is :

```
12
{5: 7}
7
6
{5: 7, 2: 4}
6
```

but what i wanted is :

```
12
12
7
6
12
6
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You do realize that you never actually memoize the *result*, right?

Comment: You don't want to `return x` you want to return that element from x. Try `return x[a]`. You also want to `compute` before you store. See @blue_note's answer

Comment: yes I do realize that, because I'm not sure how to memorize it, previously what i did is try to memorize it in an argument `c= compute(a,b)` which obviously wrong, I'm very new in programming so apologize for the rookie question

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do here: `if a & b in x:`?

Comment: what I'm trying to do here is calculate the sum of 2 integer for example `5+7` which equal to `12` and keep it in a dictionary, when the next time the number `5+7` is run again, it doesn't need to calculate again, instead just straight ahead return the result which is `12`. It an optimization task for a work I'm doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a mapping `(a, b) => value`. So

```
if (a, b) in x:
   return x[(a, b)]
else:
   value = compute(a, b)
   x[(a, b)] = value
   return value
```

Additional note: in python the logical *and* operator is `and`, not `&`.